# ROS2 equivalent of ros::CallbackInterface

Tags: ros-melodic, ros-humble, callback, callbacks

I have a legacy code that I am changing to ROS2 from ROS. I stumbled upon a class that is inheriting ros::CallbackInterface that I would like to change to ROS2.
I would like to know what is the ROS2 equivalent of ros::CallbackInterface?